# want to update a field of a DevOps workitem using Power automate. This field is a text field which should have the number of workitems created earlier

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, azure-devops

want to update a field of a DevOps workitem using Power automate. This field is a text field which should have the number of workitems created earlier. I am trying to create a list item in a sharepoint list when a new workitem is created in DevOps but not getting how to get the total no. of list items in the sharepoint list and get that count in the DevOps field 'Dem ID'.

Flow:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a connector available for Azure DevOps which have a trigger which will meet you requirement.

Refer the below screen shot.

1. Configure trigger
   [image: When a work item is created]
2. Get the work item details

[image: Get Work Item Details]

3. Create SharePoint Item

[image: Create Item in SharePoint]

4. Final Power Automate.

[image: Final Out put]

Comment: Thank you so much! it is helpful. I have reached till the step where I am able to create a list item in the sharepoint list and I am able to get the count of the items present in the list.
Now I want the count to be update in one of the fields in Devops workitem but I am getting error while trying to save the flow.

Comment: there is an action called update work item. is that not helpful?

Comment: This is the error I get:
Flow save failed with code 'DynamicParameterInputInvalid' and message 'The request to API 'visualstudioteamservices' operation 'GetWorkItemSchemaForUpdate' has invalid inputs. Error details: The API operation 'GetWorkItemSchemaForUpdate' is missing required property 'project'.'

Comment: have updated the screenshot of the flow